# C# Distance converter

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a C# Forms app for a distance converter and this is the code I have right now,I need to declare toDistance but i'm not too sure how to declare it with the results of the distance conversion. Please help if you can, I'm pretty new at this

```
private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    float fromDistance;
    float toDistance;

    fromDistance = int.Parse(distanceinput.Text);
    string measureInput = fromList.Items[fromList.SelectedIndex].ToString();
    string measureOutput = toList.Items[toList.SelectedIndex].ToString();
    distanceOutput.Text = toDistance.ToString();

    switch (measureInput)
    {
        case "Yard":
            switch (measureOutput)
            {
                case "Yard":
                    toDistance = fromDistance;
                    break;
                case "Foot":
                    toDistance = fromDistance * 3;
                    break;
                case "Inches":
                    toDistance = fromDistance * 3 * 12;
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case "Foot":
            switch (measureOutput)
            {
                case "Foot":
                    toDistance = fromDistance;
                    break;
                case "Yard":
                    toDistance = fromDistance / 3;
                    break;
                case "Inch":
                    toDistance = fromDistance * 12;
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case "Inch":
            switch (measureOutput)
            {
                case "Inch":
                    toDistance = fromDistance;
                    break;
                case "Foot":
                    toDistance = fromDistance / 12;
                    break;
                case "Yards":
                    toDistance = fromDistance / (3 * 12);
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: First time I see nested switch!! Kind of eye hurt

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you're trying to do, but don't you want the line distanceOutput.Text = toDistance.ToString(); to be after your switch statement ?

Comment: How does the rest of your form look? Why do you have all that in the event function instead of moving it into separate functions and calling those functions on the click event?

Comment: Add a control to your form and call it `output` or `results` or `toDistTextBox`. Then after you set the value of `toDistance` then set the `Text` property of your `output` textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
distanceOutput.Text = toDistance.ToString();
```

does **not** mean: "the Text of control distanceOutput should always follow whatever is the "ToString" of toDistance".

Rather it means "do that *right now*" (as in: the moment that line is executed). It doesn't keep a relation.

So the solution is to move that line *after* the (outer) switch statement where you calculate that toDistance.

However, you probably need to initialize it (`float toDistance = 0f;`) else the compiler complains that you are trying to use an uninitialized variable. It cannot see that you have used all possible values in your `switch`es.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try move distanceOutput.Text = toDistance.ToString(); to the end of function?

```
 private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            float fromDistance;
            float toDistance;

            fromDistance = int.Parse(distanceinput.Text);
            string measureInput = fromList.Items[fromList.SelectedIndex].ToString();
            string measureOutput = toList.Items[toList.SelectedIndex].ToString();


            switch (measureInput)
            {
                case "Yard":
                    switch (measureOutput)
                    {
                        case "Yard":
                            toDistance = fromDistance;
                            break;
                        case "Foot":
                            toDistance = fromDistance * 3;
                            break;
                        case "Inches":
                            toDistance = fromDistance * 3 * 12;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "Foot":
                    switch (measureOutput)
                    {
                        case "Foot":
                            toDistance = fromDistance;
                            break;
                        case "Yard":
                            toDistance = fromDistance / 3;
                            break;
                        case "Inch":
                            toDistance = fromDistance * 12;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "Inch":
                    switch (measureOutput)
                    {
                        case "Inch":
                            toDistance = fromDistance;
                            break;
                        case "Foot":
                            toDistance = fromDistance / 12;
                            break;
                        case "Yards":
                            toDistance = fromDistance / (3 * 12);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
    distanceOutput.Text = toDistance.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: I did, there was still an issue with toDistance being recognized

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your final assignment statement to after your switch.

Also, I would not use a nested switch. It's difficult to read and debug. I would convert the input to the smallest possible unit (in your case, inches). Then, I'd convert the smallest unit measurement to whatever output unit the user requested:

```
float inputInches = 0;

//Convert input to inches
switch(measureInput)
{
    case "Yard":
        inputInches = fromDistance * 3 * 12;
        break;
    case "Foot":
        inputInches = fromDistance * 12;
        break;
    default:
        inputInches = fromDistance;
        break;
}

//Convert output to desired format
switch(measureOutput)
{
    case "Yard":
        toDistance = inputInches / 3 / 12;
        break;
    case "Foot":
        toDistance = inputInches / 12;
        break;
    default:
        toDistance = inputInches;
        break;
}

distanceOutput.Text = toDistance.ToString();
```

A few additional things to consider:

- Text comparisons are messy. Consider creating an `enum` with the input types (`Inch`, `Foot`, `Yard`, etc).
- Coding in the `Button` event is also messy. Consider moving this conversion code to its own method.